# How to design table of schedule with start date and end date and year

Tags: database, database-design, data-structures

I have a table training_schedule where it has data start_date, end_date, year, course, title etc.

my current design is

- course
- title
- start_date (date)
- end_date (date)
- year_id (fk)

now my app, I needs to fetch schedules base from year or month.
(I've added year table because it is used on different parts like when we are making campaign on specific year.)

I think this design is not good because I am just ignoring the year on start_date and end_date. I am thinking about these options:

a) remove year and base the year on the start_date

b) create extra column start_month, start_day, end_day, end_month, year

or

can someone suggest a better design? also is it good to create tables for year and month? use join statement to get the name of month?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Splitting the dates out into component parts is usually a bad route to go down. As soon as you want to do date range queries, you need to reassemble them back into a date.

If you're worried about the duplication, you could make the `year` column a computed column (or whatever the moral equivalent term is in your database system) which is automatically extracted from the `start_date` column - that way you know it's always correct.

So I would go (a) with a computed column.

Comment: how about storing months on table and using join on them? is it a good practice?

Comment: @Daskul - as I said, I'd avoid splitting out the components, except (if necessary) doing so via a computed column - without knowing what your data generally looks like and the types of queries that you're going to want to run, it's difficult to give more concrete guidance.